# Prioritized Experience Replay - which version is correct?

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, dqn

After reading a lot of stuff, I'm still not sure how to calculate the priorities for Prioritized Experience Replay (PER).

[Example code taken from here](https://github.com/higgsfield/RL-Adventure/blob/master/4.prioritized%20dqn.ipynb)

```
def compute_td_loss(batch_size, beta):
    state, action, reward, next_state, done, indices, weights = replay_buffer.sample(batch_size, beta) 

    state      = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(np.float32(state)))
    next_state = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(np.float32(next_state)))
    action     = Variable(torch.LongTensor(action))
    reward     = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(reward))
    done       = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(done))
    weights    = Variable(torch.FloatTensor(weights))

    q_values      = current_model(state)
    next_q_values = target_model(next_state)

    q_value          = q_values.gather(1, action.unsqueeze(1)).squeeze(1)
    next_q_value     = next_q_values.max(1)[0]
    expected_q_value = reward + gamma * next_q_value * (1 - done)
    
    loss  = (q_value - expected_q_value.detach()).pow(2) * weights
    prios = loss + 1e-5
    loss  = loss.mean()
        
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    replay_buffer.update_priorities(indices, prios.data.cpu().numpy())
    optimizer.step()
    
    return loss
```

**(V1)** As you can see, the **weights** are used to calculate the **loss** and the **prios**. The **loss** is the mean squared error **including** the weights?

```
loss  = (q_value - expected_q_value.detach()).pow(2) * weights
prios = loss + 1e-5
loss  = loss.mean()
```

**(V2)** In "Hands-On Reinforcement Learning for Games: Implementing self-learning agents" on page 176 they use **ONE value for ALL prios**, coming from the first pow(2).mean():

```
loss  = (q_value - expected_q_value.detach()).pow(2).mean()
prios = loss + 1e-5
loss  = loss.mean()
```

**(v3)** Here loss is the mean squared error, **prios** are the **raw** errors:

```
terr  = (current_Q - target_Q.detach())
prios = terr + 1e-5
loss  = terr.pow(2).mean()
```

**(v4)** Here loss is the mean squared error, **prios** are the **squared** errors:

```
terr  = (current_Q - target_Q.detach())
prios = terr.pow(2) + 1e-5
loss  = terr.pow(2).mean()
```

**(v5)** Here loss is the mean squared error, **prios** are the **absolute** errors:

```
terr  = (current_Q - target_Q.detach())
prios = torch.abs(terr) + 1e-5
loss  = terr.pow(2).mean()
```

**(v6)** Here loss is the mean squared error, **prios** are the **squared absolute** errors:

```
terr  = (current_Q - target_Q.detach())
prios = torch.abs(terr).pow(2) + 1e-5
loss  = terr.pow(2).mean()
```

Which version is correct and why?

Thanks in advance!